some LVM commands does not correctly show PV as a part of VG (and thus also LV)
I am trying to find best command which will summarize all PV, VG and LV and display relationship between them in one output. Following PVs: sdc sdd1 sdd2 are part of lvm_tutorial VG. LV lv1 contains lvm_tutorial VG. Below are actual outputs from my machine.
root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay -C
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sdc   lvm_tutorial lvm2 a--  <5.00g     0
  /dev/sdd1  lvm_tutorial lvm2 a--   2.48g  2.48g
  /dev/sdd2  lvm_tutorial lvm2 a--  <2.51g <2.51g

root@ubuntu:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/lvm_tutorial/lv1
  LV Name                lv1
  VG Name                lvm_tutorial
  LV UUID                H3RyJx-MiFw-0Gj9-I47o-g0tg-rxzB-yeDMtI
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2024-06-02 23:28:27 +0200
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                5.00 GiB
  Current LE             1280
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0

root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay -C -o pv_name,vg_name
  PV         VG
  /dev/sdc   lvm_tutorial
  /dev/sdd1  lvm_tutorial
  /dev/sdd2  lvm_tutorial

root@ubuntu:~# vgdisplay -C -o lv_name,vg_name
  LV   VG
  lv1  lvm_tutorial

So far so good. But If i issue following command I get sdd1 displayed two times (first time is part of lv1 and second time is not) and sdd2 is not shown as a part of lv1 LV for some wierd reason. Why is this happening?
root@ubuntu:~# pvdisplay -C -o pv_name,lv_name,vg_name
  PV         LV   VG
  /dev/sdc   lv1  lvm_tutorial
  /dev/sdd1  lv1  lvm_tutorial
  /dev/sdd1       lvm_tutorial
  /dev/sdd2       lvm_tutorial

Simmilar here, sdd2 is missing and I do not know why.
root@ubuntu:~# lvs -o +devices
  LV   VG           Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  lv1  lvm_tutorial -wi-a----- 5.00g                                                     /dev/sdc(0)
  lv1  lvm_tutorial -wi-a----- 5.00g                                                     /dev/sdd1(0)

root@ubuntu:~# lvs --segments -o +devices
  LV   VG           Attr       #Str Type   SSize  Devices
  lv1  lvm_tutorial -wi-a-----    1 linear <5.00g /dev/sdc(0)
  lv1  lvm_tutorial -wi-a-----    1 linear  4.00m /dev/sdd1(0)



LV lv1 contains lvm_tutorial VG

In LVM, the most general container is volume group (VG), which can be said to "contain" other things: physical volumes, logical volumes and other mappings. Much better to think it this way: LV lv1 belongs to the VG lvm_tutorial.

But If i issue following command I get sdd1 displayed two times (first time is part of lv1 and second time is not) and sdd2 is not shown as a part of lv1 LV for some wierd reason. Why is this happening?

As it's evident from your pvs output, sdc is filled completely and sdd is partially. As you see in last lvs --segments -o +devices output, lv1 has its physical extents (PEs) placed onto sdc and sdd1. But the PV sdd1 still has some space unoccupied. So, since it contains extents of lv1 it's considered the part of it and it generates one line, but it has also some free space, and it generates another line, where no LV is shown.
Also, the sdd2 has all the space unoccupied; at last, lv1 has not a single PE placed on that PV. It is truly not a part of lv1.
All your output is coherent and everything is shown correctly.
